# How to apply encryption for any request to model?

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I have the code with which i can decrypt passwords this way:

```
use ProjectName\Models\Some; 

Some::find(1)->pass;
```

It automatically decrypt pass, which was encrypted in my DB.
But if i do different request to my model for example:

```
Some::find(1);
```

Its not work. Please someone can explain what i have to do?

This is full code:

```
trait Encryptable
{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);

        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            return Crypt::decrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::getAttribute($key);
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            parent::setAttribute($key, Crypt::encrypt($value));
            return;
        }

        parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have the code with which i can decrypt passwords this way:" You might want to read [How to Safely Store Passwords in 2016](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016). You shouldn't be encrypting passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the updated answer**

To get your expected behavior, you can override the `hydrate()` method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` to decrypt the model after database retrieval.

The original method is:

```
/**
 * Create a collection of models from plain arrays.
 *
 * @param  array  $items
 * @param  string|null  $connection
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public static function hydrate(array $items, $connection = null)
{
    $instance = (new static)->setConnection($connection);

    $items = array_map(function ($item) use ($instance)
    {
        return $instance->newFromBuilder($item);
    }, $items);

    return $instance->newCollection($items);
}
```

You can override it adding your decrypt stuff like this:

```
/**
 * Create a collection of models from plain arrays.
 *
 * @param  array  $items
 * @param  string|null  $connection
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public static function hydrate(array $items, $connection = null)
{
    $instance = (new static)->setConnection($connection);

    $items = array_map(function ($item) use ($instance)
    {
        foreach ($instance->encryptable as $attribute) {
            // Remember to do any aditional check here, like check if is_null
            // and catch any exceptions also.
            $item->$attribute = \Crypt::decrypt($item->$attribute);
        }

        return $instance->newFromBuilder($item);
    }, $items);

    return $instance->newCollection($items);
}
```

Here we solved the Decrypt part on Model loading, fine.

To solve the Encrypt on save, you can use the `saving` event to encrypt the attributes, then at `saved` event, you revert them to the non-encrypted values.

This way, on your application, the model is always plain, but on database, it will be encrypted.

Comment: in this case i even dont get into attributesToArray() function. tested it with ::all() and ::find methods

Comment: @HenryKolesnik `::all()` don't serialize the model directly, so in a `dd($model)`, you will see the original attributes, of course.

Let me suggest you another way to do what you want. I'll update the answer in a few minutes!

Comment: @HenryKolesnik take a look at this new answer!